# Ionic iPhone X statusbar white bar with updated statusbar plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I've been trying for a while now to get rid of this white bar on the top of my app when running on iPhone X. I've read in many places that updating from v2.2.0 of the `cordova-plugin-statusbar` to v2.3.0+ would get rid of this. After updating nothing changed, the white bar is still there.

What can I do to get rid of this?  I don't know what else I can try.

Any help would be great, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Make sure you look over the ios 11 check list.
http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/

Answer (score 1):

First update the viewport meta tag in your `index.html` to add the `viewport-fit=cover` field.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

In your `app.component.ts` change the color of the statusbar.

```
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";

export class MyApp {

  constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000');
      statusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
    }
  });
}
```

Or you can completely hide it with `statusBar.hide();`

[Find more info here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)